# how to dynamically set a id to a button in dialog in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple buttons with different functionality,whenever I click on a button I should get the dialog box with button in it and the button should have  the same functionality of the button that I clicked.

Note: There are many buttons in my page so how can I assign the same  functionality to the button I clicked previously.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please create a [minimal self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you are trying to do. How you are creating a dialog, where your buttons are, how your handler looks like. Without that, all we can say is "get the button you clicked and copy things" - the vaguer your question, the vaguer the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what you've tried we can only give some pointers. Here's one idea...

1. Add a jQuery `click` event for all the buttons.
2. Within the `click` function you can access the clicked button using `$(this)`.
3. Use the `.clone()` method to clone the button (`$(this)`) into your modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(event) {

    // Clear the modal
    $('#modal').html('');
    $('#modal').html($(this).clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3">Button 3</button>
<button id="button4">Button 4</button>

<div id="modal"></div>
```